# Why does my editor say "'await' has no effect on the type of this expression"?

Tags: javascript, redux, redux-thunk

Why does my editor (PHPStorm) say that I'm not gonna need 'await'? It works normally...
Here's the code:

```
export const fetchBoards = (): AppThunk =>
  async function (dispatch): Promise<void> {
    try {
      const { boards }: { boards: IBoardItem[] } = await api.get('/board');
      dispatch({ type: 'UPDATE_BOARDS', payload: boards });
      window.console.log('Success');
    } catch (e) {
      window.console.error(e);
      dispatch({ type: 'ERROR', payload: e });
    }
  };
export const addBoard = (board: { title: string }): AppThunk =>
  async function (dispatch): Promise<void> {
    try {
      const res = await api.post('/board', board);
      window.console.log(res);

      window.console.log('Before');
      await dispatch(fetchBoards()); // 'await' has no effect on the type of this expression
      window.console.log('After');
    } catch (e) {
      window.console.error(e);
      const res = dispatch({ type: 'ERROR', payload: e });
    }
  };
```

Comment: if `dispatch` doesn't return a promise, `await` accomplishes very little.

Comment: Also the functions returned by `fetchBoards()` and `addBoard()` do not return anything.

Comment: @CollinD `dispatch` in this case does return a promise though - the types for dispatch itself are just wrong.

Comment: @Pointy they are `async`, so they return a `Promise<void>` implicitly.

Comment: @phry yes but there's never going  to be a value to wait for. I guess that's the intention.

Comment: @Pointy I assume they want to wait until the api request is finished before kicking off a new request - independently of the return value.

Answer (score 3):

Because your `dispatch` is typed incorrectly and not aware of the `redux-thunk` middleware you are using.

Please set up your project up according to the TypeScript quick start https://redux-toolkit.js.org/tutorials/typescript that will give you a correct `AppDispatch` type to use for your `AppThunk` type.

Please also note that you are generally writing a very outdated (pre-2019) style of Redux - in modern Redux you would not dispatch `"ACTION_TYPES"` with manual objects and it is generally 1/4 of the code. Please read [why Redux Toolkit is how to use Redux today](https://redux.js.org/introduction/why-rtk-is-redux-today).